# Jmeter - Extracting query string in URL and BODY

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to extract the below querystring. This is implemented in URL and BODY

This is PATH

```
Common/ElectronicSignatureAcceptance.aspx?strQueryString=+JOpJVU8lPAhrezMqUcXuCxMQ16h7x4cfscbfLg(fEQjpcE7Dbyumnq%2fBRA9Y8jiZUL41GlGE3vGWC93NYqlxF0S6tZ8O4Bje2GvMeHX218yah4Twul91RAGipoqYW9oP
```

This is BODY

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="ElectronicSignatureAcceptance.aspx?strQueryString=**+JOpJVU8lPAhrezMqUcXu‌​CxMQ16h7x4cfscbfLg(fEQjpcE7Dbyumnq%2fBRA9Y8jiZUL41GlGE3vGWC93NYqlxF0S6tZ8O4Bje2Gv‌​MeHX218yah4Twul91RAGipoqYW9oP"** onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1">
```

Can someone give me the regular expression for this

Comment: Why do two asterisks appear before the query string in BODY, and then again after the action attribute closing quote? Did you add those to highlight the position of the query string, or is that raw code?

Answer (score 2):

Please use below regular expression configuration for the `PATH`.

1. Add a `Regular Expression Extractor` to your request by right click > `Add > Post Processors > Regular Expression Extractor` and config below values as shown below.

Regular Expression as `strQueryString=(.+)`

[image: Path Config]

### Output

[image: Output]

Please use below regular expression configuration for the `Body`.

1. Add a `Regular Expression Extractor` to your request by right click > `Add > Post Processors > Regular Expression Extractor` and config below values as shown below.

Regular Expression as `strQueryString=(.+) on`

[image: Config]

### Output

[image: Output]